# Ground state of sums of commuting, translated projectors

Tags: ground-state, spin-chains

I have in mind a spin chain of length $L$ with local Hilbert space dimension $d$ and projectors $\{ P_i \}$ that act on $r$ sites $i, i+1, ..., i+r-1$. The projectors are identical besides which sites they act upon. Furthermore, the projectors **all commute** with one another. Consider the Hamiltonian built out of these projectors, with periodic boundary conditions, say, $H = \sum_{i=1}^L P_i$.

Is the fact that the projectors commute enough to say that the lowest energy eigenstate of $H$ has energy exactly zero? Or is it possible that although one can write all the eigenstates of $H$ as simultaneous eigenstates of each $P_i$, there's nevertheless no simultaneous eigenstate with energy zero?

---

I'm tempted the latter is true, and some simple choice of $P$'s will work as an example where the ground state energy is greater than zero. The trouble is for me, the simple choices of commuting $P_i$'s, like taking them to be all $|\uparrow \uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow \uparrow|$, or all $\frac{1}{2}(|\uparrow \uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow \downarrow\rangle ) (\langle \uparrow \uparrow|+\langle \downarrow \downarrow|)$, nevertheless yield zero-energy ground states.

Comment: If there exists a state $|\psi\rangle$ such that $P_i|\psi\rangle=0$ for all $i$, then it must be the ground state with exactly zero energy. However, it is possible that such a state does not exist (i.e. "frustrated"), mostly due to global reasons. For a simple example, if you have an Ising chain of odd length ($L$ is odd) and the projector is $P_i=\frac{1+\sigma_i^z \sigma_{i+1}^z}{2}$ (basically neighboring spins must be anti-parallel), then you can not satisfy $P_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @MengCheng Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Not necessary, but are there any examples that you know work in OBC as well? I might ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @user196574 for OBC, take Meng's operators but also add (1-Z)/2 as a separate projector. I guess one way to say it: a zero-energy ground state will exist if the product of all your projectors is not the zero operator.

Comment: @RubenVerresen Could you clarify? The range-2, rank-3, projector $P$ that projects onto the space $|\uparrow \uparrow \rangle, |\uparrow \downarrow \rangle, |\downarrow \downarrow \rangle$ will annihilate $|\downarrow \uparrow\rangle$. I don't think the product of the $P_i$ vanishes, since the all up state is not annihilated by the product of the $P_i$. However, $\sum_i P_i$ doesn't have a zero-energy ground state, since being annihilated by a given projector $P_i$ requires $|\downarrow \uparrow\rangle_{i, i+1}$ which precludes being annihilated by $P_{i+1}$.

Comment: @RubenVerresen Maybe it would be $\prod_i (1-P_i)$?